# dynamic web badge in rails without javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic, badge

I'm trying to create a web badge with user ranking. Intend for it to be used in forums where javascript might not be enabled. I have come across this

```
<img src='http://www.x.com/vendor.gif.aspx?id=123' style='width:50px; height:50px'/>
```

from [How does one get about making a dynamic web badge using client side javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733109/how-does-one-get-about-making-a-dynamic-web-badge-using-client-side-javascript)

But i'm using ruby on rails.

Anybody has an alternative method or some hints? Thanks much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an image using [RMagick](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/) (uses imagemagick). Use the [annotate](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/draw.html#annotate) method to put text in your image.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JavaScript. Just create a Rails action, which serves the image or whatever you want to be the badge.

```
<img src="/users/123/badge" ....>
```

You may want to ask how to create an image with Rails, but that will be a different story ;-)

(ImageMagick comes to mind)

Answer (score 0):

You can create the image with RMagick on the server and then return it to the browser.

Here is a [link](http://www.kookdujour.com/blog/details/29) to an article explaining how to create images.

You'll then need the [send_data](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html) method in Rails.

I'll try and dig up a link that explains this exactly.